# How to check View type Xamarin Android

Tags: view, xamarin.android

I have an `View` element and I want to check its type like `ImageView`, `TextView` etc in Android I could do this like `(view instanceof EditText)` but couldn't find anything familiar in Xamarin Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (view.GetType() == typeof(EditText))
 {
     // Do stuff here
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(view is EditText)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

similar to Stam's answer, but takes advantage of C# is keyword.